# SolrTestCaseJ4 errors with SOLR 4.9 (works with SOLR 4.8.1)

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm trying to upgrade from `SOLR 4.8.1` to `SOLR 4.9`. Some of our test cases (using `SolrTestCaseJ4` framework) which work with `4.8.1` are failing when I try to run them with `SOLR 4.9`. 
I'm trying to figure out (and fix) the test cases.

We are using `maven surefire` plugin with `JUNIT` to run the tests.

```
Error: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.lucene.codecs.diskdv.DiskDocValuesFormat$1 cannot access its superclass org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer 
        at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([3C587EB0DE791716]:0) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) 
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) 
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) 
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585) 
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885) 
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350) 
        at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67) 
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat.reloadDocValuesFormats(DocValuesFormat.java:121) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.reloadLuceneSPI(SolrResourceLoader.java:205) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.initLibs(SolrConfig.java:587) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:162) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:139) 
        at org.apache.solr.util.TestHarness.createConfig(TestHarness.java:74) 
        at org.apache.solr.SolrTestCaseJ4.createCore(SolrTestCaseJ4.java:553) 
        at org.apache.solr.SolrTestCaseJ4.initCore(SolrTestCaseJ4.java:546) 
        at org.apache.solr.SolrTestCaseJ4.initCore(SolrTestCaseJ4.java:366)
```

From the `SOLR 4.9` Release Notes, in "**Upgrading from Solr 4.8**", I see:

> Support for DiskDocValuesFormat (ie: fieldTypes configured with
>   docValuesFormat="Disk") has been removed due to poor performance.

As a result of that, the `lucene-codecs-4.9.0.jar` doesnt have "`DiskDocValuesFormat$1`" class anymore, which somewhat makes sense.

**Question is:** What should I do to get rid of this error? since it seems to be coming from inside of `SolrTestCaseJ4`. Our code base doesn't use `DiskDocValuesFormat` for any fieldType.

From my observations, `SolrTestCaseJ4` seems to be passing different codecs (randomly) to the test cases but regardless of the codec chosen, the error is always the same mentioned above.

I found the following on the lucene forum that mentions same error that I'm getting but in a different context. No solution is mentioned, however. See link:

[Have anyone used Automatic Phrase Tokenization (AutoPhrasingTokenFilterFactory) ?](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Have-anyone-used-Automatic-Phrase-Tokenization-AutoPhrasingTokenFilterFactory-td4173808i20.html#a4195182)

Please advise as to what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks, 
Sri